# How to logout all sessions?

Tags: node.js, keycloak, logout

Keycloak Admin UI > Manage > Sessions > Logout all. Nothing happens, the app still works. How to implement this?

Using Node.js, and keycloak-connect.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show the configuration of the related client in Keycloak?

Comment: Edited the original post.

Answer (score 1):

`keycloak-connect` middleware should support Keycloak's Adapter REST API. Please try to set the `Admin URL` in your client config to the URL of your node.js app.

Comment: Can you please also help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71164387/keycloak-multiple-log-in-pages-attempts-error?

Comment: Found another use case. This works for sessions, but not for disabling the user.

Comment: As long as you have a session (or valid token) disabling the user will not be effective for that session. Only during next login the user won't be able to login. That's by design.

Comment: Yeah, also figured out that one out yesterday by the tooltip in Keycloak admin. Thanks for the explanation.